# Win10(version 1709)へVMWareToolsをinstallするとVMが落ち起動不能となる

Tags: windows-10, vmware

ESXi6.0へVMを作成しWin10(fall creators update)をinstallしました。
このVMへVMWareToolsをinstallしようとしたところ、install途中にVMが落ちてしまい、起動不可能な状態になってしまいました。
Win10(fall creators update)へはVMWare Toolをinstallできないんでしょうか？

Win10(version 1507)では、VMWareToolsのinstallを正常に終了できましたが、その後WindowsUpdateでfall creators updateへ更新中に起動不可能となってしまいました。

最悪、VMWareToolsを入れずに使おうとは思っているんですが...
回避可能な情報があれば教えていただけると嬉しいです。

---

ESXi6.0
Windows10 Pro(version 1709:fall creators update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolsはesx6.0に付随するバージョンですか？
もしそうであれば、より新しい VMwareTools 10.2.0 等ではどうでしょうか。

下位バージョンesxもサポートしますよ。

Comment: https://my.vmware.com/jp/group/vmware/details?productId=614&downloadGroup=VMTOOLS1020 試しに入れてみます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ESXiとVMWareToolsって一緒にversion上げんとダメなもんだと思いこんでました。32bit環境も64bit環境も10.2.0ならinstallできました。ちゃんと動作してるように見えます。